# Filtering unrecognized tags using php

Tags: php, regex, tags

I need to retrieve untagged content from a string.
This is how an input would look like.

```
<!--[recognized]-->This is a recognized tag<!--[/recognized]-->
<!--[unrecognized]-->This is an unrecognized tag<!--[/unrecognized]-->
and this is normal text
```

Having the list of recognized tags, I need some cute and simple method that destroys the "recognized" tag
and the normal text so I can have the pure unrecognized thing.

This is how I'm doing it right now, but as you'll see I'm using two regexes. I want it to be just one.

```
$recognized_tags    = implode( '|', array( 'recognized', 'foo', 'bar' ) );
$pattern            = '/<!--\[(?<tag>(' . $recognized_tags . '))\]-->(?<tag_content>.*)<!--\[\/\k<tag>\]-->/s';
$parcial_result     = preg_replace( $pattern, '', $text );

preg_match_all( '/<!--\[(?<tag>.+)\]-->(?<tag_content>.*)<!--\[\/\k<tag>\]-->/s', $parcial_result, $matches );
$result = implode( $matches[0] );
```

So, do you know how could I do it using just one regex?
Note that the input string may vary and there's more than one tag ( recognized or not ).

Thx a lot!

Comment: Don't try to use a regex for this.

Comment: Is there self closing tags?

Comment: And can the tags to be nested?

Comment: I'll take a look at the html whitelist thing.
Yes, there are self closing tags ( the ones eith the / ).
And yes, tags can be nested :(

Comment: How looks a self closing tags? like this: `<!--[tag/]-->`?

Comment: They look like this: <!--[/tag]-->

Comment: @googol: But it is the same as a closing tag! A "self-closing tag" is a tag like img or br or hr in html that doesn't need a closing tag.

Comment: Oh! I completely misunderstood! There are no self closing tags, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: To find the content from unrecognized tags: (coming soon)

Old response:
To find text that is not enclosed between tags, you can apply this pattern to your raw `$text` string (without making any replacement before):

```
$text = <<<'LOD'
<!--[recognized]-->This is a recognized tag<!--[/recognized]-->
<!--[unrecognized]-->This is an unrecognized tag<!--[/unrecognized]-->
<!--[atag]-->
    <!--[nested1]--> text
        <!--[nested2]-->text<!--[/nested2]-->
    <!--[/nested1]-->
<!--[/atag]-->
and this is normal text
LOD;

$pattern = '~(<!--\[([^]]++)]-->(?>[^<]++|(?1))*+<!--\[/\2]-->)*+\K[^<]++~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Pattern details:

```
~                       # delimiter
(                       # capturing group 1: will capture all tags with content inside
    <!--\[([^]]++)]-->  # the opening tag: the capturing group 2 contains the name of the tag
    (?>                 # atomic group: all possible content inside tags 
        [^<]++          # all characters except <
      |                 # OR
        (?1)            # an other tag: recursion to the capturing group 1
    )*+                 # repeat zero or more times the atomic group
    <!--\[/\2]-->       # the closing tag with a backreference to the 2nd capturing group
)*+                     # repeat zero or more times the capturing group 1
\K                      # IMPORTANT: the \K resets all the precedent match from match result before itself
[^<]++                  # the result: all characters that are not a <
~
```

The general idea of this pattern is to match all potential tags before "the normal text" and then resets this part from the match result with the `\K` feature.

note: to avoid blank results and to trim leading spaces you could add this to the pattern:

```
$pattern = '~(?>\s++|(<!--\[([^]]++)]-->(?>[^<]++|(?1))*+<!--\[/\2]-->))*+\K[^<]++~';
```

Comment: Wooot! Could do explain this a bit, please?

Comment: @googol: Is everything clear?

Comment: Yep, the regex is clear and I've learned a lot about it!
But it does not fullfill my needs :(

Maybe my question wasn't clear... But what I really need is to get the content from the 'unrecognized' tags ( the ones that are not in a list I have ).